# Design Pattern for Callbacks OPTIONALLY on UI Thread

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm designing an API that makes heavy use asynchronous code-completion blocks.

```
public interface IResult<T extends Result.I> {
    void onResult(T);
}

public void doXYZ(IResult<Result.TypeA> iResult) { ... }
```

The user would call my API's doXYZ(), and a separate networking worker thread would later call iResult.onResult() . Sometimes he doesn't care which thread onResult() gets called on, other times he may only want to update UI -- just looking for a way to invisibly offload the burden on the user, so they can keep their anonymous inner classes neat and small.

This API is for Android, where many (but not all) times, the user may want do do something in the onResult() callback that affects UI elements, thus necessitating that their code runs on the UI thread. Rather than burden the user with having to dirty up their code with runOnUIThread(...) invocations, I'm wondering if folks know of a design pattern that will make it easy, at the time of the doXYZ() invocation, for the user to specify whether the callback is to be called on their UI thread.

1. For performance reason, I'd rather not force that my API always call onResult() on the UI thread.
2. One pattern I've seen is add a method parameter: doXYZ(... , boolean callOnUIThread). However, since the API is documented, I'd rather not dirty up the documentation (and method signature) by having all those additional booleans.
3. Another thought was to overload each doXYZ(), to have one with and one without the callOnUIThread parameter, but that's incredibly bad for documentation because of the bloat.
4. Another thought I had was to add a onResultUI() method to IResult, in addition to onResult(), but that dirties up the user's code by having them have to always define both in their anonymous classes.

Any suggestions on a clean way to accomplish this that's:
 i. concise
 ii. great for code readability
 iii. easy on documentation
?

Comment: Think about the usage code: do you know at the point of creating the `IResult` instance if the code needs to run on the gui-thread? In that case you could provide a marker interface `IRunsOnGui` which the client can extend from if he wants `onResult` to run on the gui-thread. When you add your `IResults` check if it is an instance of `IRunsOnGui` and only allow the result to run on the gui-thread. You can see an example of this [here on ideone](http://ideone.com/whEDB2). If this answers your question I'd be happy to put it in an answer.

Comment: So basically `doXYZ` is dispatching asynchronous jobs that'll report their results via the interface. In this case both marker and decorator are well suited (and even combinable as you see in my [ideone-link](http://ideone.com/whEDB2): in the example Foreman bob would do the dispatching, `bob.dirve` would be your `doXYZ`). Choose any you like: give the callee the control by either decorating his `IResult` or marking it to be run differently. In `doXYZ` perform the check whether to dispatch to your general worker pool or to the gui-thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a decorator pattern for the `IResult`.

E.g. If you have an interface `IResult` (I just made the generic type T easier for the demo)

```
interface IResult<T> {
  void onResult(T result);
}
```

and a result callback implementation like this

```
class PrintCurrentThreadAndResult implements IResult<String> {
   @Override
   public void onResult(String result) {
   Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
    System.out.print(thread.getName());
    System.out.print(" - ");
    System.out.println(result);
   }
}
```

you can create a decorator that ensures that the decorated result will be invoked on a special thread (e.g. the ui thread). I use swing's event dispatcher thread here so that everyone can easily compile and test it.

```
class UIThreadAwareResult<T> implements IResult<T> {

  private IResult<T> delegate;

  public UIThreadAwareResult(IResult<T> delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  @Override
  public void onResult(T result) {
    invokeOnUIThread(result);
  }

  private void invokeOnUIThread(final T result) {
    try {
      EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          delegate.onResult(result);
        }
      });
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

client code can then choose the thread to run on by just decorating the original result.

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();

    IResult<String> result = new PrintCurrentThreadAndResult();
    main.doXYZ(result);

    IResult<String> uiThreadAwareResult = new UIThreadAwareResult<String>(result);
    main.doXYZ(uiThreadAwareResult);
  }

  public void doXYZ(IResult<String> iResult) {
    iResult.onResult("Hello");
  }
}
```

The output will be

```
main - Hello
AWT-EventQueue-0 - Hello
```

Comment: @BeyelerStudios since I don't know how the OP's `doXYZ` method is implemented I use `invokeAndWait`. It might be that the `doXYZ` method first calculates some result, then passes it to the `IResult` and finally does something more that must be synchronized with the `onResult` method.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios What do you mean with 'even run in a worker thread'?

Comment: I read the OP's *an API that makes heavy use asynchronous code-completion blocks* as: he's either running asynchronous computations and providing an interface of how to handle the results (`onResult`) or he's somehow dispatching the `onResult` asynchronously. Your decorator would in both cases run the `invokeAndWait` on the worker thread, so the code completion is not actually asynchronous.

Comment: I mean ... the onResult() will mostly be called by a networking worker thread, so it'll be an altogether different thread than the one the user would use to invoke the doXYZ().